# Replace every n'th occurrence in huge line in a loop

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have this line for example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I want to insert a newline (\n) every 2nd occurrence of "," (replace the 2nd, with newline) .

Comment: what have you tried ? use a for loop and use a boolean, shouldn't be difficult

Comment: Yes, and also: what is the expected output?

Comment: When people post comments requesting clarification, you should [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: When people respond to your question at all, you should in turn respond at all ;)

Answer (score 20):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/\n/2;P;D' file
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add an explanation why it works. Thanks

Comment: @Taavi the `s/,/\n/2` command replaces the second `,` with a newline. The `P` command prints upto and including the first newline in the pattern space. The `D` command deletes upto and including the first newline, then, if the pattern space is not empty repeats all the sed commands from the first but does not replace the pattern space by the next line as the `d` command would. Thus the pattern space is converted into multiple lines until it is completely consumed when the next line is introduced.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' | sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
```

seems like the most straightforward way. `\([^,]*,[^,]*\)` will capture `1,2`, `3,4`, and so forth, and the commas between them are replaced with newlines through the usual `s///g`. This will print

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't add comment to wintermutes answer but it doesn't need the first `,` section as it will have to have had a previous field to be comma separated.

```
sed 's/\(,[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
```

Will work the same

Also I'll add another alternative( albeit worse and leaves a trailing newline)

```
echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" | xargs -d"," -n2 | tr ' ' ','
```

Comment: Reply to "it will have to have had a previous field to be comma separated". I disagree with your this statement, @wintermute answer just add a more readable intent, it will work even if there's nothing before the first coma as it match 0 or unlimited times a non coma character. Any field could be empty and in this case the regex will stop matching at the second  coma and print a single coma followed by a newline.

Comment: @Tensibai Nothing is still a field.

Comment: I don't get your comment, I'm just saying the other answers works as yours but is more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk to do this:

```
$ awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%2?FS:RS) }' file
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
```

It loops through each field, printing each one followed by either the field separator (defined as a comma) or the record separator (a newline) depending on the value of `i%2`.

It's slightly longer than the sed versions presented by others, although one nice thing about it is that you can alter the number of columns per line easily by changing the `2` to whatever value you like.

To avoid a trailing comma after the last field in the case where the number of fields isn't evenly divisible, you can change the ternary to `i<NF&&i%2?FS:RS`.