# How do i replace comma before a specific string with \n in csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a `csv` file and I want to replace a comma with `\n` after `GCA_*`.

**Input:**

```
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1,ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio,ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
```

**Desired output:**

```
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1
ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio
ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
```

**My attempt:**

```
sed 's/ASM*/\n&/' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv > assembly_report_table.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried? You've tagged your question with awk and sed, so I'd expect to see some awk and sed code in it that you need help with.

Comment: i tried with sed command, but didn't work for me                                                     sed 's/ASM*/\n&/' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv > assembly_report_table.csv

Comment: Please add your attempt to your question. (That will probably stop and perhaps reverse the downvotes.) We'd love to help you fix your code, but your code should be part of the question. Also, your question states that you want to add a newline after `GCA_`, but in your sample output, the second newline is not after this text. Can you clarify?

Comment: The tile says you want to replace before a string (I think `ASM`), what is confirmed by your desired output and your attempt. The first line of the question should be changed, you mention `GCA_` what is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\(GCA_[^,]*\),/\1\n/g' input.csv
```

- `\(GCA_[^,]*\),`: matches `GCA*` followed by a comma. The `\(...\)` define a group that we can later use in the replacement string.
- Replacement `\1\n`: Inserts the group ("GCA*") from the match and append a newline.

To change the file directly:

```
sed -i 's/\(GCA_[^,]*\),/\1\n/g' input.csv
```

Or to fix your command line from the comment:

```
sed 's/ASM[^,]*/\n&/g' input.csv
```

Or better: To prevent trailing comma:

```
sed 's/,\(ASM[^,]*\)/\n\1/g' input.csv
```

Comment: Doesn't work in BSD or macOS. If you don't know if the OP is using the same version as you are, it's better to construct your answer so that it's portable.

Comment: @ghoti Restricted to "GNU sed"

Comment: @ghoti Could you provide a portable answer. I would like to learn more.

Comment: The issue is that non-GNU sed doesn't interpret ANSI backslash notation like `\n`. The canonical way to embed a newline into the replacement string is to use a literal newline preceded by a backslash. You might do this in bash using format quoting, like so: `sed $'s/,ASM/\\\nASM/g' input.csv`. You can read about `$'..'` under "QUOTING" in the bash man page.

Comment: Though in this case, I think the OP is really looking for a split every 16 fields, as mickp suggested, so: `sed $'s/,/\\\n/16;P;D' input.csv` would likely be my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This simple [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) might be what you are looking for:

```
$ sed 's/,/\n/16;P;D' file
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1
ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio
ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E.coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
```

- `s/,/\n/16`: replaces the 16th comma `,` with a newline `\n`
- `P`: prints the line up to the first newline `\n`
- `D`: deletes the printed text and starts the cycle again with the remaining text

---

It is based on a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464574/6176817) by [@potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong).

Comment: A line of explanation about what the `sed` command means, exactly, would be great.

Comment: It certainly comes from a great answer but it's an answer to a different question. OP didn't specify that GCA_ will always be at the 16th occurrence. 

Comment: @Tomalak added explanation :) @TrebuchetMS it certainly looks like OP has a long line that just needs to be formatted to be a proper `csv`. I think it's a fair assumption that each `csv` row has the same amount of fields and therefore I can use a constant, such as `16`.

Comment: I second that assumption. Also, the OP's sample input is already contradictory: There is no `CGA_` in the second record.

Comment: Another way to do this *16th* comma method:  `xargs -d, -L 16 echo < file`

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `*` and add `g` for global:

```
sed 's/ASM/\n&/g' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv > assembly_report_table.csv
```

When you don't want the comma, you can use

```
sed 's/,ASM/\nASM/g' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv > assembly_report_table.csv
```

For fun, with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="ASM"} NF {print "ASM" $0}' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv
```

When you don't want the comma at the end of the line, you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="[,]*ASM"} NF {print "ASM" $0}' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

awk solution:

```
$ awk -F, '{i=0;while((++i)<=NF)printf $i ((!(i%16) || i==NF)? ORS : ",")}' mb.csv
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1
ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio
ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
```

It's similar to [mickp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061514/5403468), 16 fields as a line.
If you are sure the input file has only one line, you can remove the first `i=0;`.

If the 'ASM' is relatively unique, can use your own way(ASM as line beginning):

```
awk '{print gensub(",ASM","\nASM","g")}' mb.csv
```

That is:

```
awk '{print gensub(",ASM","\nASM","g")}' ordered_lines_per_genome.csv > assembly_report_table.csv
```

for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl and assuming the id starts with ASM..

```
$ cat maryem.txt
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1,ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio,ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
$ perl -pe ' s/([^^]ASM.+?,)/\n$1/g; s/^,//mg; ' maryem.txt
ASM190063v1,Escherichia coli(E.coli),strain=D3,562,SAMN03252421,PRJNA269191,Nanjing Agricultural University,2016-12-12,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,Newbler v. 2.7,30-80x,Illumina Miseq; Roche 454 GS Junior,GCA_001900635.1
ASM301855v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2013C-4225,562,SAMN08579596,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-3-26,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,76.725x,PacBio
ASM330895v1,Escherichia coli (E. coli),strain=2017C-4109,562,SAMN09534373,PRJNA218110,CDC,2018-7-10,n/a,major,Complete Genome,full,HGAP v. 3,yes,286.7X,PacBio
$
```