# Bash build multiple comma separated lists limited to N items from one bigger list

Tags: bash, shell

I have a huge list (some million rows) of values of this type:

```
abcx437u2bz;dhnauih41291
bbvcae13421;fjhllalsi432
...
```

I need to build many smaller lists this way:

```
abcx437u2bz,bbvcae13421,...
```

so only the first part before `;` should be taken and values should be split in smaller comma separated lists, limited to 1000 items in one row.

How can I accomplish this in a bash script so I can automate this task?

Comment: Explain downvote please so I won't make the same mistake again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F';' -lane 'BEGIN { $, = "," }
                  push @vals, $F[0];
                  if (@vals == 1000) { print @vals; @vals = () }
                  END { print @vals if @vals }' inputfile
```

Comment: I ended up using this one. Short, fast, and easy to edit.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` you can say something like:

```
nr=1
while IFS=";" read -r a rest; do
    str+=",$a"
    if (( nr % 1000 == 0 )); then
        echo "${str#,}"
        str=""
    fi
    nr=$(( nr + 1))
done < file.txt
[[ -n $str ]] && echo "${str#,}"
```

However `bash` may not be suitable to deal with a huge file and it will take several minutes to process millions of lines.
Instead you can say with `awk` as:

```
awk -F";" '{
    str = str "," $1
    if (NR%1000 == 0) {
        print substr(str, 2)
        str = ""
    }
}
END {
    if (length(str)) print substr(str, 2)
}
' file.txt
```

which will accelerate the execution time by tens of times.

Comment: Potential poblem with that is that unless the last line number is a multiple of 1000, there'll be a trailing comma on the last line of output.

Comment: @Shawn thank you for pointing out. I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk (for three strings on a line. For a thousand on a line, replace all `NR%3` with `NR%1000`):

```
$ awk -F\; '{
    printf "%s%s%s",(NR%3==1?"":","),$1,(NR%3==0?ORS:"")
}
END {
    printf "%s",(NR%3==0?"":ORS)
}' file file file                # emulating more data with multiple calls to the file
```

Output for 6 record of data:

```
abcx437u2bz,bbvcae13421,abcx437u2bz
bbvcae13421,abcx437u2bz,bbvcae13421
$
```

Output for 4 records of data (2 calls to file):

```
abcx437u2bz,bbvcae13421,abcx437u2bz
bbvcae13421
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Very compact solution

```
C=1;MAXPERLINE=1000;SEP="";RESULT="";for i in $(<hugeListFile);do FIRST=$(echo "$i" | cut -f1 -d\;); RESULT=$RESULT$SEP$FIRST;SEP=",";[ $C -eq $MAXPERLINE ] && { echo "$RESULT";(( C=1 )); RESULT="";SEP=""; };(( C=$C+1 ));done; echo "$RESULT"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d';' -f1 input_file | paste -sd, | sed 's/,/\n/100;P;D'
```

First with `cut` extract the first field. Then join all the fields using a comma with `paste`. Then use `sed` to replace every 100 comma with a newline as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455379/replace-every-nth-occurrence-in-huge-line-in-a-loop).

Tested with:

```
cat <<EOF >input_file
abcx437u2bz;dhnauih41291
bbvcae13421;fjhllalsi432
a;b
c;d
e;f
g;e
1;2
3;4
5;6
7;8
9;0
a;s
d;f
g;h
EOF
cut -d';' -f1 input_file | paste -sd, | sed -E 's/,/\n/4;P;D'
```

outputs:

```
abcx437u2bz,bbvcae13421,a,c
e,g,1,3
5,7,9,a
d,g
```